# Twitter API - Python - 150 Request/Hour Even after authenticating

Tags: python, api, rest, twitter

I'm creating a Application with python twitter API. I want to make a lot of status calls to twitter.
I understand unauthenticated calls are limited to 150 an hour.

So I went ahead and authenticated myapp through my twitter account. Still I'm getting only 150 requests an hour . As per the Document, I should be getting 350 requests a hour.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting#rest

I used OAuth to authenticate my app,

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
consumer_secret='consumer_secret', access_token_key='access_token', access_token_secret='access_token_secret')
```

How can I get to 350 requests/hour. If I want more, where I can request it?

Comment: checked using api.verifyCredentials(). Looks like twitter is not able to authenticate me from my desktop. Is it because, I gave the url for my app and I'm accessing from desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably waay too late on  this one. I had this issue. I believe it happened because I was logged into the Twitter(website) on my personal account(not the account I setup for my app) while running my app. Once I got a new access token, I was back to 350, and was able to verify my credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you issue an invalid OAuth request to public Twitter endpoint, Twitter treats it like an anonymous request and returns data, along with an `X-Warning` header indicating that the request was not authenticated correctly.  So if you are only able to request an API endpoint 150 times an hour, you're most likely generating your OAuth signature incorrectly - check the `X-Warning` header in the response from the API to make sure.

It's difficult to tell what might be wrong from the snippet you posted.  Which library are you using?  How are you making the HTTP request to the API endpoint?

Comment: Hi Arne,I'm using http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/ . Here is the error , I'm getting Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitterfeed.py", line 38, in <module>
    get_conversations("vanchinathan")
  File "twitterfeed.py", line 24, in get_conversations
    print api.VerifyCredentials()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\twitter.py", line 3453, in VerifyCredentials
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\twitter.py", line 3668, in _ParseAndCheckTwitter
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\twitter.py", line 3691, in _CheckForTwitterError
twitter.TwitterError: Could not authenticate you.

Comment: How are you configuring the library?  It's a shame that that client library doesn't really expose the raw HTTP response for errors :(